# Xml error ,getting error Unexpected end tag string in values.xml in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I am getting red line at resources starting tag and end tag ,and at the tag of `Sciatica4` I'm getting error

> Error:(1616) Unexpected end tag string
>
> Error:(1616) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional
>   format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt

**Values.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  getting red line here  ---- >    <resources xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
                <attr format="reference" name="constraintSet"/>
                <attr format="reference" name="drawerArrowStyle"/>
                <attr format="dimension" name="height"/>
                <attr format="boolean" name="isLightTheme"/>
        .
        .
        .

 <string name="Sciatica1">  Turmeric: Add 1 teaspoon of turmeric to 1 cup of milk. You can also add a small cinnamon stick. Boil the solution. Sweeten this healthy drink with honey and drink it once or twice daily until you see improvement.</string>
    <string name="Sciatica2">  Valerian Tea: Drink valerian tea prepared by steeping 1 teaspoon of dried valerian root in 1 cup of hot water for 10 minutes. Drink this herbal tea several times a week for a few weeks.</string>
    <string name="Sciatica3">  Hot or Cold Compresses: Place a hot or cold pack on the affected area for 15 to 20 minutes.Do this every few hours until you get relief.</string>
   <string name="Sciatica4"> Capsaicin Cream: Buy a cream or ointment containing 0.025% to 0.075% capsaicin.Apply it on the affected area up to 4 times a day, at least for 1 week.</string>
    .
    .
    .

    </resources><----getting red line here
```

Answer (score 0):

These aren't going in values... Please, paste them in your string file.

```
<string name="Sciatica1">  Turmeric: Add 1 teaspoon of turmeric to 1 cup of milk. You can also add a small cinnamon stick. Boil the solution. Sweeten this healthy drink with honey and drink it once or twice daily until you see improvement.</string>
<string name="Sciatica2">  Valerian Tea: Drink valerian tea prepared by steeping 1 teaspoon of dried valerian root in 1 cup of hot water for 10 minutes. Drink this herbal tea several times a week for a few weeks.</string>
<string name="Sciatica3">  Hot or Cold Compresses: Place a hot or cold pack on the affected area for 15 to 20 minutes.Do this every few hours until you get relief.</string>
<string name="Sciatica4"> Capsaicin Cream: Buy a cream or ointment containing 0.025% to 0.075% capsaicin.Apply it on the affected area up to 4 times a day, at least for 1 week.</string>
```

> Note: Values file only accepts attribute oriented tags.

Answer (score 0):

You get it wrong.

**Values** is a folder in resource(res) directory.

You have to paste all your string content into **strings.xml** .

```
<string name="Sciatica1">  Turmeric: Add 1 teaspoon of turmeric to 1 cup of milk. You can also add a small cinnamon stick. Boil the solution. Sweeten this healthy drink with honey and drink it once or twice daily until you see improvement.</string>
    <string name="Sciatica2">  Valerian Tea: Drink valerian tea prepared by steeping 1 teaspoon of dried valerian root in 1 cup of hot water for 10 minutes. Drink this herbal tea several times a week for a few weeks.</string>
    <string name="Sciatica3">  Hot or Cold Compresses: Place a hot or cold pack on the affected area for 15 to 20 minutes.Do this every few hours until you get relief.</string>
   <string name="Sciatica4"> Capsaicin Cream: Buy a cream or ointment containing 0.025% to 0.075% capsaicin.Apply it on the affected area up to 4 times a day, at least for 1 week.</string>
```

Like that .make **attrs.xml** in your res directory and paste this in it.

```
<attr format="reference" name="constraintSet"/>
                <attr format="reference" name="drawerArrowStyle"/>
                <attr format="dimension" name="height"/>
                <attr format="boolean" name="isLightTheme"/>
```

Comment: i posted all things in strings.xml file but it automatically taking it in values.xml file ..when i deleted all the strings from values on rebuild it automatically again taking it.....

Comment: @anshulsinha  values.xml is a runtime file . so check your file  title at the time of error.  it might be something like this . `debug/balues.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Keep the below strings in your **string.xml** file

```
 <string name="Sciatica1">  Turmeric: Add 1 teaspoon of turmeric to 1 cup of milk. You can also add a small cinnamon stick. Boil the solution. Sweeten this healthy drink with honey and drink it once or twice daily until you see improvement.</string>
    <string name="Sciatica2">  Valerian Tea: Drink valerian tea prepared by steeping 1 teaspoon of dried valerian root in 1 cup of hot water for 10 minutes. Drink this herbal tea several times a week for a few weeks.</string>
    <string name="Sciatica3">  Hot or Cold Compresses: Place a hot or cold pack on the affected area for 15 to 20 minutes.Do this every few hours until you get relief.</string>
   <string name="Sciatica4"> Capsaicin Cream: Buy a cream or ointment containing 0.025% to 0.075% capsaicin.Apply it on the affected area up to 4 times a day, at least for 1 week.</string>
```